# distorted normal map

Tags: normal-map

I'm struggling with this for quite some time so posting here.
I sculpted a portrait (left) and with [Instant Meshes](https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes) I retopologized it (right).

When I try to bake normals the map image is distorted and the normals are not right. I tried to flip normals and the objects must be at the same place...
Don't know...

[image: sculpted head and retopologized head]

[image: baked normal map]

Blend file: [portrait6.blend (googledrive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_YDwe1b85t_ecS1gYSQN8rd0FdpzaXfw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi and welcome. I had a look at your blend file and added an image to your question. If you enable the *Face Orientation* overlay, you see that there are some flipped normals (twisted mesh at the shoulders) and holes (behind the ears of the remeshed head). This causes glitches on the baked image. Another thing is that the remeshed head has more vertices than the sculpted one. This made me wonder why you want to bake the normal map at all? The purpose of a normal map is to add the details of a high-poly mesh to a low-poly mesh. But your remeshed head is not low-poly.

Comment: Agree with Blunder. What's your goal here?

Comment: I wanted to rig the face .. I had no idea the remeshed head had more vertices.. well thanx anyway..

Comment: Instant-Meshes is a good tool to get a quad structured mesh. But the created mesh isn't ideal for face rigging. If you want to rig the face with facial expressions it's better to [retopologize it manually](https://youtu.be/SwM19PgSdCM), or use a [base mesh](https://dikko.gumroad.com/l/jrULR) and [transform it into the sculpted version](https://youtu.be/LSdKpYtNy_U). Then you have a clean low-poly mesh and can bake the normal map to transfer the details.